# Gmail IMAP php mail send as reply of email

Tags: php, gmail, imap, reply

I want to send an email as reply in gmail through my Laravel CRM system.

My code is as below:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.Auth::user()->f_name.' '.Auth::user()->l_name.'<'.$gmail_address.'>'." \r\n" .
                        'Reply-To:  <'.$gmail_address.'>'. "\r\n" .
                        'Subject: '.$subject."\r\n".
                       'To: '.$to."\r\n".
                        'In-Reply-To:  <56F15324.7050704@xxxx.xxx>'. "\r\n" .
                        'References: <56F15324.7050704@xxxx.xxx>'. "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

imap_mail ( $to , $subject ,$body,$headers);
```

But it sends it as a new email, i.e not as a reply.

Ideally it should add "Re: " to subject and append the actual email at the end of reply email body.

Any Help please..

Comment: You have to append the original email by yourself. IMAP will not do it for you. There is no magic happening in imap_mail method.

Comment: @awons but then it will be a new mail, not a reply, I want to  do it like thread in gmail.

Comment: I don't follow. Try with imap_mail_compose to create appropriate headers. With "In-Reply-To" and "References" you can tell Gmail that it is a reply but you have to attache the original message by yourself.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your `In-Reply-To` and `References` headers are hardcoded to some magic value; that's probably not what you want to do.

Here is how I would improve the code:

- Use a library which handles the rather low level bits of RFC2047, RFC2231 and especially RFC 5322 for you. It's very likely that any non-ascii characters in your user's `l_name` produce a non-compliant message. Read the whole RFC5322 to understand how e-mails work. Read about various encodings which come into play.
- Track the `Message-Id` of the message(s) that you're replying to, and set your own `In-Reply-To` & `References` headers accordingly.